# Thus <p> and other element have their own padding

Tags: html, css, margin

I set the body to `margin : 0;` as well as in padding. Would you mind if I ask if I create a `p` element it will create their own respective padding.

[image]

Thanks I'm a newbie, trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's not a Padding, it's a Margin.

Because `<p>` tag has a default css values which is:

```
/* Default CSS Values */
p {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

So the space between `<p>` tags is coming from `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, and if you want to clear this space just add a css rule like this:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u can reset Paragraf like body.
So u can set css for paragraf.

```
p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

option 2
if u want reset all Tag like p, img, a, ul, li or etc. U can try Meyer Reset CSS

Thanks

Comment: actualy the code is place on body, 
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} however when i try to add a new tag it consume a new space, i dont think if it is a block element

Comment: every element have default margin and padding. if u want reset all element u can try. 

    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear, do you mean something like this?

```
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

You can also use inline tags. Inline tags will override all other load time styles.

```
<p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
  Hello World
</p>
```

Comment: instead on p tag i added it on body tag body, 
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} how ever when i try to add new element it takes space as you can see on the image...do you think because of it is a block element

Comment: Adding those properties to the html/body of the document the set the margin and padding of the page - not the elements within it as they are not inherited by default. You need to manually assign these to elements to override their default settings.